# Mapbox: How to collapse layer control ON CLICK instead of hover?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

For the default mapbox layers toggle icon, how do you collapse the control on mouse click rather than hover? ANd then, how would you uncollapse on another click?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [code for the layers control](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/control/Control.Layers.js#L74) might be helpful.

You want to instantiate the layers control with the `collapsed` option set to `false`, then attach event handlers to its container, calling the (private) methods `_collapse` and `_expand` as needed.

Also, it should be possible to make a small Leaflet plugin to make a custom layers control with expand-on-click behaviour (and thus prevent calls to "private" methods from outside).